# How to make Syntax trees for these sentences?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I am having trouble drawing a syntax tree for these sentences and I would appreciate it if someone could help me right now.

> Why did Ella, one of my friends, who always comes on time to the class where we usually use to learn syntax seriously and in which we met her for the first time rent the motorcycle where horn was broken because of the accident which happened 2 weeks ago when the day was raining?

I would also be thankful if you can explain to me how to draw it, because I do not understand it very well.

Comment: ***Dear***? Sorry, that's not an auspicious greeting for the general public, especially when you're asking a favor. If you don't know this much, what do you need syntax trees for? The only people who ever use syntax trees are syntax teachers, and they don't agree on how they should be made. Ask your teacher. Or make it up; that's what they do.

Comment: ok forgive me, I still learn about english language so that I need help. :D

Comment: Learn English first, before you attempt syntax trees. Learn to walk before you try running.

Comment: How can i ask my teacher if the question itself from my teacher :D , so who can please help Me how to make a tree diagram. thanks before!

Comment: thanks for the advice, I've learned but also do not know so I need help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like a solicitation to do someone's homework. Also, Stack Exchange requires askers to have basic understanding of the topic being discussed, and to provide with some evidence of a minimal attempt to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: @bytebuster Basic understanding is not necessarily required, sometimes you ask for something new and unknown. That is, unless I misunderstood what you said... :P But I agree with the rest.

Comment: @user2753 Show us what you tried, by editing yourquestion, and ask specific problems (some specific issues you don't understand). Your question is rather general and huge, and it's unlikely you'll find someone willing to answer it as is. I'd suggest following the advice you had in the comments.

Comment: Copy-paste the sentence here: http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.